# ¿Cómo agregar una imagen en Flutter con formulario login?

Tags: imagen, google-api, flutter, dart

Soy nuevo en **flutter** y estoy intentando agregar una imagen en una misma pantalla la cual contiene el login, pero tengo el siguiente error:

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
flutter: Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
flutter: Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container.In this case, a vertical
flutter: viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation
flutter: typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.
flutter: If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because
flutter: there will always be enough vertical space for the children. In this case, consider using a Column
flutter: instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size
flutter: the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.
```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:validate/validate.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Login',
      home: new LoginPage(),
    ));

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginData {
  String email = '';
  String password = '';
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  _LoginData _data = new _LoginData();

  String _validateEmail(String value) {
    // If empty value, the isEmail function throw a error.
    // So I changed this function with try and catch.
    try {
      Validate.isEmail(value);
    } catch (e) {
      return 'Debe ingresar un RUT válido.';
    }

    return null;
  }

  String _validatePassword(String value) {
    if (value.length < 6) {
      return 'La contraseña debe ser al menos de 6 caracteres..';
    }

    return null;
  }

  void submit() {
    // First validate form.
    if (this._formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save(); // Save our form now.

      print('Printing the login data.');
      print('Email: ${_data.email}');
      print('Password: ${_data.password}');
    }
  }

  @override
  //Colores
  final morado = const Color(0xFF913a90);
  final naranjo = const Color(0xFFf15a24);
  final gris = const Color(0xFF525252);
  final double textSize = 40.0;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Espacio Seguro'),
          backgroundColor: morado,
        ),
        body: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Image.asset(
              'images/logo_login.png',
            width: 80.0,
            height: 100.0, 
            ),
            new Container(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: new Form(
                  key: this._formKey,
                  child: new ListView(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new TextFormField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType
                              .emailAddress, // Use email input type for emails.
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Ejemplo: 12.304.248-5',
                            labelText: 'Ingresar RUT',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                          ),
                          validator: this._validateEmail,
                          onSaved: (String value) {
                            this._data.email = value;
                          }),
                      new TextFormField(
                          obscureText: true, // Use secure text for passwords.
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Ingresar contraseña',
                              labelText: 'Ingresar Contraseña',
                              icon: Icon(Icons.lock)),
                          validator: this._validatePassword,
                          onSaved: (String value) {
                            this._data.password = value;
                          }),
                      new Container(
                        width: screenSize.width,
                        child: new RaisedButton(
                          child: new Text(
                            'Ingresar',
                            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          onPressed: this.submit,
                          color: naranjo,
                        ),
                        margin: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: traduce tu pregunta, estas en la versión en español de SO, de lo contrario terminará cerrada

Comment: I want to add image **** with login FormField.

Comment: translate your question @Adrian Tapia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es porque tienes 2 `ListViews`, una dentro de otra y no especificas el tamaño de la primera.

Puedes solucionarlo de 2 formas:

1- Elimina el `ListView` principal y agrega la imagen dentro del `ListView` con tu contenido.

```
    body: Container(
                    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: new Form(
                      key: this._formKey,
                      child: new ListView(
                        children: <Widget>[
                         new Image.asset(
                            'images/logo_login.png',
                          width: 80.0,
                          height: 100.0, 
                          ),
                          new TextFormField(
                              keyboardType: TextInputType
                                  .emailAddress, // Use email input type for emails.
                              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                hintText: 'Ejemplo: 18.604.258-1',
                                labelText: 'Ingresar RUT',
                                icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                              ),
                              ....
```

2- Al segundo `ListView` ponle la propiedad `shrinkWrap:true` para que no se expanda completamente y se ajuste al contenido.

```
     body: new ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Image.asset(
                  'images/logo_login.png',
                width: 80.0,
                height: 100.0, 
                ),
                new Container(
                    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: new Form(
                      key: this._formKey,
                      child: new ListView(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new TextFormField(
                              keyboardType: TextInputType
                                  .emailAddress, // Use email input type for emails.
                              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                hintText: 'Ejemplo: 18.604.258-1',
                                labelText: 'Ingresar RUT',
                                icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                              ),
                              validator: this._validateEmail,
                              onSaved: (String value) {
                                this._data.email = value;
                              }),
                          new TextFormField(
                              obscureText: true, // Use secure text for passwords.
                              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: 'Ingresar contraseña',
                                  labelText: 'Ingresar Contraseña',
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.lock)),
                              validator: this._validatePassword,
                              onSaved: (String value) {
                                this._data.password = value;
                              }),
                          new Container(
                            width: screenSize.width,
                            child: new RaisedButton(
                              child: new Text(
                                'Ingresar',
                                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              onPressed: this.submit,
                              color: naranjo,
                            ),
                            margin: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )),
              ],
            )
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @diegoveloper ocupé la 2da alternativa y funciona.